# Combining Multidimensional Arrays with zip_longest

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to combine two unequal arrays:

```
array1 = ['a','b','c','d']
array2 = ['1','2','3']
```

I'm using the code:

```
name_num = [x for x in zip_longest(array1, array2, fillvalue = '0')]
```

And it's returning this as the new array:

> [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3'),('d','0')]

However, I would like it to return as a multidimensional array such as:

> [['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3'],['d','0']]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert each tuple that `zip_longest` outputs to a list with the `list()` constructor:

```
name_num = [list(x) for x in zip_longest(array1, array2, fillvalue = '0')]
```